# Toggle class of an element with given id

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<dl>
  <dt id="1"><a href="#">One</a></dt>
  <dd class="hidden" id="1">Test one</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt id="2"><a href="#">Two</a></dt>
  <dd class="hidden" id="2">test Two</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt id="3"><a href="#">Three</a></dt>
  <dd class="hidden" id="3">test three</dd>
</dl>
```

When some1 clicks on a `<dt>` element i want to change the class of `<dd>` with the same id to `"show"`

Here is my script:

```
$(document).on('click', 'dt', function () {
    var fq=$(this).attr("id");
    $("dd").removeClass("hidden").addClass("show");
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

With the above code, i can get the id of the clicked `<dt>`, but how do i change the class of the `<dd>` with the same id?

Comment: Id's are unique. Use classes instead!

Comment: You can't do that. An ID needs to be unique and I think not start with a number. Why not use `data-id=""` or something.

Comment: is your intention to show or hide DD of respective DT ?

Comment: It was to show the DD of the respective DT, but with $(this).next('dd').toggleClass("hidden","show"); i can now show/hide it.

Comment: well instead of setting respective classes for hide and show you can call the jquery`s `hide()` or `show()`, which prevents u from defining css styles for hide and show functionality.like this `$(this).next('dd').show();`

Comment: Well, there are already css styles for show and hidden classes, since they are included in bootstrap's css. That why i want to toggle classes since native showing or hiding is not working for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).on('click', 'dt', function () {
    $(this).next('dd').removeClass("hidden").addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: I think this was i wanted. It works. I'll accept when i can.  $(this).next('dd').toggleClass("hidden","show"); was even better.